# Put characters from a char array in a string till a specific character is found

Tags: c, arrays, string

I'd like a reliable method to read the characters from a character array and put them in a string. This will happen till a `\r` is found. I can iterate through the array but have no good way to put that in a string. I am afraid to use `malloc` since, at times, puts garbage value in a string.

Here `payload` is the `HTTP` data from a TCP packet. `\r\n\r\n` indicates the end of the payload.

My code so far to iterate through the character array:

```
void print_payload(const unsigned char *payload, int len) {

        int i;
        const unsigned char *ch = payload;

        for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                if (strncmp((char*) ch, "\r\n\r\n", 4) == 0) {
                        // Indicates end of payload data.
                        break;
                } else if (strncmp((char*) ch, "\r\n", 2) == 0) {
                        //Indicates EOL
                        printf("\r\n");
                        ch++;
                        i++;
                } else if(strncmp((char*) ch, "Host:", 5) == 0){
                        printf("Host: ");
                        const unsigned char *del = ch + 6;
                        int i = 0;
                        while (del[i] != 13 ){   
                           /* 
                            *13 is decimal value for '\r'.
                            * The characters below are to be inserted
                            * in a string. Not sure how though.
                            */

                                printf("%c",del[i]);
                                i++;
                        }
                } else if(strncmp((char*) ch, "User-Agent: ", 11) == 0){
                        /*
                         * It has to implemented here as well.
                         * And in every case where my string matches.
                         */
                        printf("UserAgent: ");
                        const unsigned char* del = ch + 11;
                        int i = 0;
                        while(del[i] != 13){
                                printf("%c")    
                        }

                }                
                ch++;
        }

        printf("\r\n\r\n");
        printf("\n");

        return;
}
```

Can somebody help me achieve this? I know this is basic but I'm still learning C Programming and am not sure how to do this. Thank in advance.

Comment: `strncmp((char*) ch, "\r\n\r\n", 4)`  in the first part of code makes little sense.  The state of `ch` is unknown.  Without the calling code or the deeper restrictions on calling `print_payload()`, code makes little sense.  Posts a [mcve].`

Comment: @chux My bad sir. I will edit and correct it right away..

Comment: `while(del[i] != 13){printf("%c") }` You should use `'\r'` instead of a number. Also please provide code that actually compiles. There is a `;` missing. Finally: This loop will run forever as `i` never changes. And if it would change, you might run behind the `'\0'` terminator if you don't find a `'\r'` earlier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few options. First, if you can limit the size of the string, and do not need it outside of the function, then a char array would work:

```
#define STRING_MAX_LEN 999//chux mentions this is better then just putting "1000" in the array[] - 1000 needs to make sense in terms of the program, or something you wish to enforce (and checked!)
char newString[STRING_MAX_LEN+1] = {0};//Initialize to NULL value.
```

There is no reason to fear `malloc` though - just remember to work safely and free, and you should be fine:

```
char *newString = malloc(sizeof(char)*(len+1)); //Better limit on needed space - +1 for a final '\0'.
if (!newString) //Oh no! hard fail.
    //do Something
}
memset(newString,0,sizeof(char)*(len+1)); //No garbage in my new string anymore!
...
...
free(newString);
//Finish up with program
```

You will not even have to append a `'\0'` - you are already sure the buffer is full of them, so you a valid C string. Note `sizeof(char)` may be redundant but I like to keep it anyway, in case one day it will not equal 1.

Note if you have to return the new string for some reason you must use a dynamically allocated array, using `malloc`. Finally, if you only need to check/hold one sub-string at a time, then re-using the same string is preferable.

Comment: `*1000` is a vague idea.  In effect, you are saying allocate large enough so code need not worry.  Robust code does worry and that the value whatever it is, needs to  be tested to  insure no overflow.

Comment: @chux I did not want to add too many invented words, but I will use a define to make it explicit you have to know or enforce a hard limit.

Comment: @chux Edited in something close to what I probably would have done if I wanted a hard-coded limit.

Comment: @kabanus this is a great mechanism. Thanks for this. But I have to implement this in other `else if` cases as well. Should I create new `char array` for each of them or should I use the same one and just copy it to new string variables for further processing?

Comment: @DevanshuMisra Depends on the use case. If you need to only hold one array at the time, then use the same one. Once you are done with it, just set the first character to `\0` so it is marked as an empty string, and remember to append the end-character it when you are done filling it as well. If you need to **return the string** then you must use `malloc`, as the array is only a locally allocated object..

Answer (score 0):

```
void print_payload(const unsigned char *payload, int len) 
{
    int i;
    char c;
    char *p;

    p = (char*)payload;
    for(i=0;i<len;i++) {
        if(!strncmp(&p[i],"\r\n\r\n",4)) {
            c = p[i+4];
            p[i+4] = 0;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(i==len) {
        return;
    }
    printf("%s\n",p);
    p[i+4] = c;
}
```